# Where can I see exactly how many rads I have?

Tags: fallout-4

Basically, I don't want to waste any RadAway if, for example, it will remove 300 rads and I only have 150. Especially if I'm low on RadAway and/or not near a doctor.

In Fallout 3/New Vegas, I'm used to seeing some number on my Stats page of the pip boy (from what I remember, maybe it was somewhere else exactly). Did Fallout 4 completely remove the exact number and I just have to guess based on my health bar? Or am I missing some other location that will tell me how much I have?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there was an option on the 'Stats' tab of the PipBoy that shows your current stats, which include hp and rad. Not at home to check it, but I think it was one of the 'press a key while on this tab' options, and not another tab. Not making this an answer as I don't remember 100%, but I am pretty sure I saw it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution while tediously studying the pip boy.
While it doesn't give an *exact* number, there is a gauge to the right of the main pip boy screen that reflects how much radiation you've contracted.

You cannot really determine it down to the exact rad, but should be able to guess to within 10 or so rads. As far as I can see, there is no rads bar or anything in the actual pip boy screen itself (as there was in FO3 or New Vegas).

If anyone finds it difficult to read the gauge, zooming in a bit (with the touchpad on a dualshock) makes it a little easier.
And as rpmerf commented, right click zooms on PC.

Comment: right mouse click to zoom in on the computer

Comment: On Xbox One, if you remap the Pip-Boy button (I mapped it to what the-button-formerly-known-as-Back), and press that button again with your Pip-Boy open, the Pip-Boy will move closer to the screen.

Comment: @AnthonyW I think it's the back button regardless. I had the Pip-Boy mapped there as well, and then went back to the default. It makes more sense now, as the back button is the change perspective button, meaning it changes the zoom out of the Pip-Boy as well.

Comment: Change perspective button makes sense. That's the touchpad on PS4.

Comment: I think the button-formerly-known-as-Back on XB1 is more of a "context menu" button these days or something. Either way, I still call it "Select" just like I still call the one next to it "Start". And I usually refer to RB/RT as R1/R2, etc.

Comment: Also, my PB is mapped to R3 (clicking the right stick) and I'm pretty sure "Select" still zooms.

Comment: Based on these late answers, people may not understand that each rad is 0.1% of your health. That knowledge is necessary to understand how the gauge lets you calculate rads. Should probably add that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is rather complicated. Each person's health is different so you need to calculate it. First pick up a lot of Rads. At least half is your health. Then take a radaway. You know a radaway cures 300 rads. So you need to see what percentage that heals by fully healing yourself. And calculating the ratio for your health level. Example I have 365 health. For me radaway only cleared 30% of my health which was 110 health. Once you have that ratio then you can calculate your tags at any time with that given health. When you level you will have a different ratio.

Comment: A rad is 1/1000th of your health, so 300 rads is always 30% of your health. If you knew your exact rad percentage, you could always figure out how many rads that was directly, but that's not explicitly listed anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your Medic perk, a fully maxed out medic perk restores all health from stimpacks and all radiation from radaways. For an easier way to check your rads, go onto a power armour because once you're inside the power armour, a different GUI/HUD will appear showing you the percentage of your health instead of a green bar. Now you can check how many rads you've got. If your radaways eliminates 30% of the rads then it'll how that it deducted 30% on your rads on the health meter.

Comment: The green bar is also a percentage, it's just displayed horizontally rather than radially. Don't see how upgrading the medic perk helps determine the number of rads. Last sentence makes no sense, grammatically... maybe you meant 'show' instead of 'how'. It's not 30% of the rads, it's rads equivalent to 30% of your health, which is exactly 300 rads, regardless of how much health you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your pip-boy, there will be a meter on the right-hand side.
You can also get a brief idea if you look at your HP bar, there is a small percentage of the bar which is red. It shows up here because the more rads you have gained, the less health you have overall.
I hope that helped :D

Comment: While this answer is correct, it doesn't add anything that hasn't been previously stated in other answers.